# Why AT commands gives different results on different devices

Tags: bluetooth, call, at-command, hfp

I am sending AT commands to an android/ios device from windows over a bluetooth(hfp) connection  and when I checked some AT commands like ATD,AT+CLCC,ATA,AT+CHUP give same results on all devices but AT+CNUM gives different results on different devices, so is it because of a different android versions or bluetooth versions.

I wanted to know on which sim i am getting a call if i have a dual sim device over a bluetooth connection with AT commands.
Right now on Oppo F11 pro (Android 11,Bluetooth v:4.2) AT+CNUM gives the sim number on which i am receiving a call but on other devices like pixel 6a,Iphone 12 pro, One Plus 10t it gives the default sim information not the one i am using for call.

Comment: HFP AT commands are defined in HFP docs. So to understand which one is supported and when you need to refer to that doc.

Comment: AT+CNUM is supported by HFP but the problem is it gives different result on different devices. @MikePetrichenko

Comment: HFP defines that for correct processing +CNUM command you must establish a service level connection. That does mean that you should not only connect to HFP profile but also execute some AT commands to establish a service level connection (refer to p.81 HFP v1.8). "If multiple numbers are available, the AG shall send a separate +CNUM response for each available number" (p.81 GFP v1.8).

Comment: ok but i already know this ,my question is why AT+CNUM gives different results on different devices @MikePetrichenko

Comment: You are probably attributing information to the "+CNUM" command that is not there according to the specification.

Comment: sorry @Risto but i didnt get what you are trying to say because in HFP official docs for mobile devices it says mobile devices support AT+CNUM

Comment: The [current specification](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/hands-free-profile-1-8/) says: *This procedure allows HF to query the AG subscriber number.* It doesn't say anything about *I wanted to know which sim I am getting a call on if I have a dual sim device*. So what you see on your Oppo is completely manufacturer specific and not based on any standard.

Comment: so is there any other way to know on which sim i am getting a call over a bluetooth connection or any other wireless connection  @Risto

Comment: No, HFP does not define such behaviour. Usually first connected/activated SIM used (or preferred from phone's settings). Of course some devices may provide custom non-standard AT commands.